# Error with default AWS DHCP with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I've got an error while I'm trying to add some tags to default DHCP while VPC is creating.

```
Error: Multiple default DHCP Options Sets found
```

As it is not associated with VPC, it should not give me any errors, but I can not fix it.
Here is a new DHCP determination:

```
resource "aws_vpc_dhcp_options" "dhcp" {
   count                             = var.create_network && var.enable_dhcp_supporting ? 1 : 0
   depends_on                        = [aws_vpc.network]

   ntp_servers                       = var.ntp_servers
   domain_name                       = var.domain_name
   domain_name_servers               = var.domain_servers
   netbios_name_servers              = var.netbios_name
   netbios_node_type                 = var.netbios_type
   
   # ^ Resource Lifecycle ! Timeouts Does Not Supported
   lifecycle { create_before_destroy = true } 
   tags = merge(
     {
         "Name"  = join(" | ", [
             format("%s Network | ${var.dhcp_tag} · %s", var.identity_tags, var.master_cidrblock_ipvf),
             upper(var.region)
         ])
     },
     var.resource_tags,
     var.optional_tags,
   )
}
```

Here is the default DHCP determination:

```
resource "aws_default_vpc_dhcp_options" "dhcp_default" {
   tags = merge(
     {
         "Name"  = join(" | ", [
             format("%s Network | Default ${var.dhcp_tag} · %s", var.identity_tags, var.master_cidrblock_ipvf),
             upper(var.region)
         ])
     },
     var.resource_tags,
     var.optional_tags,
   )
}
```

As you may see, I'm working with non default DHCP, but the default DHCP should apply those changes

Comment: Terraform docs indicate default dhcp options is per region, not per vpc

Comment: Thanks, for reminding, but as I said the default DHCP in my humble opinion should not be conflicted

Comment: I've also looked for `tfstate` file, but default `dopt` does not exporting

Comment: 1. Does the problem happen also when you remove the first `aws_vpc_dhcp_options`?
2. Do you happen to "call" the `default` twice - e.g. placed in a module you include twice?

Comment: Hello, @GrzegorzOledzki

1. No when I remove the `aws_vpc_dhcp_options` the are no errors, however in docs there is no conflict

2. The module called only once, no duplicates